# How to use Vue on click to toggle/ deactive an active html class?

Tags: css, vue.js

I am trying this peace of code to toggle class by vue on-click event. But not working and showing bunch or errors in console. Can you help me ?

```
<div id="app5">
    <h1>Dynamic CSS</h1>
    <h2>Example 1</h2>

    <div
            v-bind:class="{available: value}"
            v-on:click="available = !available">
        <span>Click</span>

    </div>
</div>
 

var app5=new Vue({
    el:'#app5',
    data:{
        value: true,
        nearby:false
    }
});
```

## sylesheet

```
  span{
        background:red;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .available span{
        background: green;
    }
```

#### I am expecting the span background will initially green but red after click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your click handler, you're trying to toggle the `available` variable, which is actually the name of your css class. The syntax for class binding is the following: `v-bind:"{classtotoggle: variable}"`.

So you should have written:

```
<div v-bind:class="{available: value}" v-on:click="value = !value">
  <span>Click</span>
</div>
```

As an advice, I'd always use a function to handle event (`v-on` directive), It makes it easier to add behaviour in the future.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

You have to toggle `value` onclick `v-on:click="value = !value"` check below code.

```js
var app5=new Vue({
    el:'#app5',
    data:{
        value: true,
        nearby:false
    }
});
```

```css
span{
        background:red;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .available span{
        background: green;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app5">
    <h1>Dynamic CSS</h1>
    <h2>Example 1</h2>

    <div
            v-bind:class="{available: value}"
            v-on:click="value = !value">
        <span>Click</span>

    </div>
</div>
```